# adafruit LSM9DS0 Library - ok with Uno but compile error with LinkitOne?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, library, adafruit, magnetometer

I'm calling an adafruit Flora LSM9DS0 magnetometer using the Adafruit library with the following sketch:

```
        #include <Wire.h>
        #include <SPI.h>
        #include <Adafruit_LSM9DS0.h>
        #include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>  // not used in this demo but required!

        unsigned long timeNow = 0;
        unsigned long mSecInHour = 3600000;
        unsigned long TimeNow =0;
        int millisecs =0;
        int seconds = 0;
        byte minutes = 0;
        byte hours = 0;

        int mag_raw_x;
        int mag_raw_y;
        int mag_raw_z;

        // i2c
        Adafruit_LSM9DS0 lsm = Adafruit_LSM9DS0();

        // You can also use software SPI
        //Adafruit_LSM9DS0 lsm = Adafruit_LSM9DS0(13, 12, 11, 10, 9);
        // Or hardware SPI! In this case, only CS pins are passed in
        //Adafruit_LSM9DS0 lsm = Adafruit_LSM9DS0(10, 9);

        void setupSensor()
        {             
          // 2.) Set the magnetometer sensitivity 
          lsm.setupMag(lsm.LSM9DS0_MAGGAIN_2GAUSS);          
        }

        void setup() 
        {
        #ifndef ESP8266
          while (!Serial);     // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc
        #endif
          Serial.begin(9600);

          // Try to initialise and warn if we couldn't detect the chip
          if (!lsm.begin())
          {

            while (1);
          }
          Serial.println(F("Found LSM9DS0 9DOF, measurements in Gauss"));
         }
         void loop() 
        {
          lsm.read();
          TimeNow = millis(); 
          mag_raw_x = lsm.magData.x;
          mag_raw_y = lsm.magData.y;
          mag_raw_z = lsm.magData.z;
```

Which compiles and runs fine on the Arduino Uno, but I don't understand why the same sketch causes this compile error in the LSM9DS0 library when I compile for the LinkitOne?

```
    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp: In member function 'bool Adafruit_LSM9DS0::begin()':

    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp:77:16: error: 'SPCR' was not declared in this scope

         SPCRback = SPCR;

                    ^

    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp: In member function 'void Adafruit_LSM9DS0::write8(boolean, byte, byte)':

    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp:365:18: error: 'SPCR' was not declared in this scope

           SPCRback = SPCR;

                      ^

    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp:374:7: error: 'SPCR' was not declared in this scope

           SPCR = SPCRback;

           ^

    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp: In member function 'byte Adafruit_LSM9DS0::readBuffer(boolean, byte, byte, uint8_t*)':

    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp:415:18: error: 'SPCR' was not declared in this scope

           SPCRback = SPCR;

                      ^

    C:\Users\elbg\Arduino\libraries\arduino_373648\Adafruit_LSM9DS0.cpp:426:7: error: 'SPCR' was not declared in this scope

           SPCR = SPCRback;

           ^
```

Any suggestions welcome !

Comment: The SPCR register is low level programming for SPI on a Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adafruit library for the LSM9DS0 is written to run on an 8-bit Arduino. The LinkitOne isn't - it's an ARM board.

Either get a different library that is written to work on ARM, write your own library to work on ARM, or don't use that combination of components.